# Populate ListView from List<Object>

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Basically I have a list of objects of class Ingredient which looks like this:

```
class Ingredient {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    public Ingredient(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

so each object from list have a name.

Now to use ArrayAdapter I need to have a List of strings filled with names.
Is there any way to use ArrayAdapter with my list of Ingredients?
This is how it looks right now

```
List<Ingredient> ingredientsList= new ArrayList<Ingredient>();
ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("foo"));
ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("bar"));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the below. You can use a for loop and populate your `ingredientsList`. The below is just a example

```
List<Ingredient> ingredientsList= new ArrayList<Ingredient>(); 
Ingredient i= new Ingredient("foo");   
ingredientsList.add(i);
Ingredient i1= new Ingredient("bar");   
ingredientsList.add(i1);
```

Then

```
 ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
 // initialize listview
 lv.setAdpater(new CustomAdapterArrayAdapter(ActivityName.this,ingredientsList));
 // set the custom adapter to listview
```

You can use a `CustomAdapterArrayAdapter` inflate a custom layout

```
public class CustomAarrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
{

List<Ingredient> ingredientsList;
public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Ingredient> list)
{
   super(context,0,list);
   ingredientList = list;
}

@Override 
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
ViewHolder holder; 

if (convertView == null) { 
convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
// inflate custom layout called row 
holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.tv =(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.is.textView1);  
// initialize textview
convertView.setTag(holder);
}
else
{
      holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
      Ingredient in = (Ingredient)ingredientsList.get(position);
      holder.tv.setText(in.name); 
      // set the name to the text;

return convertView;

}

static class ViewHolder
{

   TextView tv;
} 
}
```

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

ViewHolder is for smooth scrolling and performance

row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

Without using custom adapter

```
class Ingredient {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    public Ingredient(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.name.toString();
    }

}
```

Then

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
List<Ingredient> ingredientsList= new ArrayList<Ingredient>(); 
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        ingredientsList.add(new Ingredient("foo"+i));
    }
   ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Ingredient>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ingredientsList);
   ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
   lv.setAdapter(adapter);
  }
  }
```

Then

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: I avoided to create CustomAdapter :) but I will create it because I don't see any other solving left.. ps. I forgot initially to add Ingredients to list ... mistake :)

Comment: @smotru with custom adapter you can customize your layout and style the textview the way you want. What is the issue with CustomAdapter any way?

Comment: I don't have any problem with CustomAdapter. Actually i'm just researching. Tried to make this tutorial [link](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-create-listview-in-xml-and-populate-items-using-arrayadapter/). They used "String[] sports". I was trying to find a way to implement my list of ingredients without creating new layout or adapter.

Comment: @smotru you can do that also

Comment: Iterating my list and creating the String[] array with the names of the ingredient? Or do you have any other idea?

Comment: @smotru i din't understand what you meant by iterating list. Pls check my edit without custom adapter but with dummy values. Do note that `toString` is overriden

Comment: ok, you just answered to more questions that I had. Thanks :)

Comment: @smotru this displays one 1 textview. if you want to display id also then go for custom adapter. just add another textview to row.xml in the previous code before edit. and make sure you initialize id in Ingredient class

Comment: Yes, I will use custom adapter for my customized layout. But again it was only for learning some basics. Is this "// TODO Auto-generated method stub" written by your editor ?

Answer (score 1):

Extend the array adapter class:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Ingredient> {

    Activity activity;

    public MyAdapter(Activity context, int resource,
            List<Ingredient> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.activity = context;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Ingredient currentIngredient = getItem(position);

                //Do Something
              ....
        }
```